# Symfony __construct usage

Tags: php, symfony, constructor, symfony4, php-7.1

I am relatively new to Symfony (version 4) and trying to implement the `__construct` method for dependency injection.

Currently, I am "injecting" dependencies via my own implementation (before I was aware of the `__construct` method) like so:

**routes.yaml**

```
fetch:
    path: /fetch/{req}
    controller: App\Controller\Fetch::init
    requirements:
    req: ".+"
```

/fetch route calls the `init()` method, which serves as the constructor.

**Controller Class**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use App\Services\Utilities; // a bunch of useful functions

class Fetch extends BaseController {

    private $u;

    public function init(Utilities $u) {

        $this->u = $u; // set the $u member with an instance of $u
    }

    private function do_fetch(){

        $this->u->prettyprint('hello service'); // use one of $u's methods
    }
}
```

If you would indulge me, I came up with this ad-hoc scheme *before* reading [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html), which detail this almost exactly (I get a cookie).

The one difference is that the docs use `__construct()` in place of my `init()` method. The following is an example from the doc page linked above:

```
// src/Service/MessageGenerator.php

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getHappyMessage()
    {
        $this->logger->info('About to find a happy message!');
        // ...
    }
}
```

But when I swap `init()` for `__construct()`, and update the routes.yaml, I get an error.

```
// .....

class Fetch extends BaseController {

    private $u;

    public function __construct(Utilities $u) {

        $this->u = $u; // set the $u member with an instance of $u
    }
    // ....

fetch:
    path: /fetch/{req}
    controller: App\Controller\Fetch::__construct
    requirements:
    req: ".+"
```

[image: error]

Its asking me to provide an argument to `__construct` since that method takes one (`$u`) but this was *not* the case when `init()` was acting as the constructor.

Moreover, I feel like since the `__construct()` method is a built-in hook, Symfony should know to use it without my having to explicitly tell it to in routes.yaml. However, excluding it throws an error as well.

**routes.yaml (__construct not explicitly indicated)**

```
fetch:
    path: /fetch/{req}
    controller: App\Controller\Fetch
    requirements:
    req: ".+"
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Controllers are created before the action is called.  Therefore you can't use the constructor as your action.  Add an action method and point to it in your route.  Both the constructor and the action will end up being called. Oddly similar to the examples in the docs.  And you actually can have a method called [__invoke()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#invokable-controllers) which will make your last example work.

Answer (score 0):

`__construct` is a magic method in PHP. The problem with your `init` method is that it does not enforce that the object **must** have an instance of the object you need in order to be built. Sometimes an object property will not be needed. In this case, I recommend creating a [setter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) as a way to optional set that property.Try to make your class properties private, and only allow them to be mutated or retrieved through setters and getters...this will provide a standard API to your obejct, and avoid random state manipulation.

You can use the [DIC](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) in Symfony's router to construct your controller instead of extending the base controller class by [registering your controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/4.1/controller/service.html). This greatly decouples you code and allows all kinds of additional flexibility. You should always favor composition over inheritance.